# FTP server with TLS does not work in windows file explorer and browsers

Tags: server, windows, vsftpd, tls

When I finish configuring my TLS, I try to connect from the Windows file explorer and from browsers with ftps:// ftpes:// sftp:// and user:password@server:port and also as a network unit but nothing worked.

After several days of research I have verified that windows does not support SFTP/FTPS/FTPES connections.

The only solution for this problem is that if the user wants to 'see' the files by these means, he can list them.

You must use other applications such as Filezilla or WinSCP for this type of connections and make the transfers, edits and deletions that you want.

For this you have to change two parameters of vsftpd.conf

`force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO`

The only problem is that it doesn't seem safe and there must be some way to make this connection.

I was looking for if the permissions can be varied according to the protocol by which the user connects, to allow listing/viewing the content without being able to do other actions such as deleting or changing things, but I can't find anything either.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions that you have seen? Thanks.

Comment: The server configuration is done in ubuntu. But problems arise when I connect from windows.

Comment: That's what I don't know, partly in windows problem but I don't know if any solution for this problem can be configured from ubuntu.
And I cannot assure you that my configuration is correct, only that I find it curious not to find a question like mine here.

Comment: The problem I have is what I explain. That windows doesn't accept the TLS and I don't know why. But I want to know if there is anything I can do in ubuntu. Other configuration or if someone who has TLS or SSL has configured and have no problems with these means.

Comment: Neither Windows Explorer nor Windows `ftp.exe` support SFTP/FTPS/FTPES. There's nothing you can do about that on Ubuntu side.

Comment: I will leave the question still open in case I find any solution. Or if someone informs me of something.
Thank you for confirming some doubts I had.

Answer (score 0):

For sftp take a look at an explorer extension called "swish"
So if your server is capable of running an sftp subsstem, that might do the trick for you.

For FTP over SSL (or anything else that goes beyond plain FTP), there is no support in the file explorer and also no known extension which could add that functionality for you.

However, since Martin is participating in this discussion, maybe he can take a look at the issue within the scope of his excellent WinSCP software in the future?
There is clearly a need. This is by far not the only thread about similar questions out there.